# Contextual Version Conflict

Tags: quantum-computing, qiskit

I'm trying to develop a qiskit noise model using pennylane-qiskit, but there seems to be some issue betwee the packages.

Here is the code I'm running in my juptyer notebook.

```
import qiskit
import pennylane as qml
import qiskit.providers.aer.noise as noise

# create a bit flip error with probability p = 0.01
p = 0.01
my_bitflip = noise.pauli_error([('X', p), ('I', 1 - p)])

# create an empty noise model
my_noise_model = noise.NoiseModel()

# attach the error to the hadamard gate 'h'
my_noise_model.add_quantum_error(my_bitflip, ['h'], [0])

dev4 = qml.device('qiskit.aer', wires=1, noise_model = my_noise_model)
```

The error is on the last line. Here is the specific error message.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFSNQ.png)

I've tried reinstalling the packages and fiddling with the different versions.